# I am trying to read, append and sort all words in a file using Python in TextWrangler application.

Tags: python, list, file, split, append

**Question**:
Open the file romeo.txt and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order.

```
fname = raw_input('Enter the file name: ')
file = open(fname)
romeo = list()
for line in file:   
    words = line.split()    
    for current_word in words : 
        if current_word in romeo:   
            continue
        romeo.append(current_word)
print romeo.sort()
```

I am getting an output of "None". I am not sure what I am doing wrong
[This link is where the romeo.txt file is found.](http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/romeo.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `None` is because `romeo.sort()` does the sorting in place, so it actually returns nothing. You have to actually just print `romeo` after you call `romeo.sort()`.

So, instead of printing `romeo.sort()`, just print:

```
print(romeo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without **continue**:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    word = line.split()
    for item in word:
      if item not in lst:
            lst.append(item)
            lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Answer (score -1):

fname = input("Enter file name: ")

fh = open(fname)

lst = list()

for line in fh:

```
x=line.split()

for word in x:

if word not in lst:
    lst.append(word)
    lst.sort()
```

print(lst)

Comment: Your answer is appreciated but as of now it only consists of code. Adding some text explaining your answer would help out the asker and others more.

Comment: Your code indentation is incorrect, so the code will not work. Please [edit] your answer and fix the indentation, then mark the code as a code block so that it will display correctly (easiest way is to highlight the code and press control+K or command+K). Formatting guidelines are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)